# Docker container run and pause right after

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker service/image I'm using which restarts as soon as starts.

I'm unable to fix the issue by getting into the container using

```
docker exec -it CONTAIER_NAME
```

since it restarts/terminates as soon as it boots.

Is there anyway I can pause it directly? I can't rebuild the image as I don't have access to the internet on the server. (Yes I'm sure the rebuild or `build--no-cache` will fix the issue)

The issue should be easily fixable if I modify permissions for a certain folder, but I'm not sure how to do this inside the container when I can't access it. The image doesn't have a docker file and is used directly from the docker hub.

Comment: run it with a custom entrypoint (`docker run ... -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash CONTAINER_NAME`) and start the program manually. This should show whatever error(s) occur.

Comment: create a Dockerfile that uses the image in the FROM instruction and fix the permission via RUN instruction.

Comment: Please post your  Dockerfile.

Comment: @Turing85 this worked perfectly, thanks. you can post this as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

If we do not get any information from the container's logs, we have the option to start the process "manually". For this, we start the container with an interactive terminal (`-it`, `-i` to keep STDIN open, `-t` to open a pseudo-TTY) and override the entrypoint to be a shell, e.g. `bash`. For good measure, we want the container to be removed when it terminates (i.e. when we exit the termainal, `--rm`):

```
docker run ... -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash
```

Once inside the container, we can start the process that would have normally started through the entrypoint from the container's terminal and extract error information from here.